# How can I replace oe with ö while typing it?

Tags: keyboard, input

I generally use the US layout on my devices because I dislike German layout, but it's annoying having to press Compose to type ä, ö, ü, ß etc. On Windows I have an AutoHotKey script that replaces oe with ö etc. when I type it on my keyboard with the ["hot strings"](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#auto) option. Is there any program/hack I can use to get this on Linux?

This is the script I'm using on Windows with AutoHotKey:

```
:*?:ue::ü
:*?:ae::ä
:*?:oe::ö
:*?:sss::ß
```

This is how it looks while typing:

[image]

Edit: To clarify, I'd like this to work globally on an X11 server. It'd be nice if I could toggle it on/off without rebooting for stuff where I don't need it (I only need it when typing German texts). I use i3wm without a full desktop environment everywhere, but I can install a program of a DE if necessary. Also, I'm messing around with [libuiohook](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook) atm and might hack something together that does that, I'll update it here when it works :)

Comment: Clearly you rarely need to edit configuration files like `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` ;-)

Comment: If you're on X, I *think* Xcompose would work.

Comment: what do you do if you need to write a word like `poem`, or `doesn't`...?  I guess `o`-space-backspace-`e` would be an option, but... Anyway, what I did on my laptop was to edit the keymap to my liking, e.g. to have `[{}]` where they are on the US layout, but have `öä` right under them like on the Finnish layout.

Comment: You should add some information about your environment. Console, graphics, Gnome, KDE, globally or just one application? Would keyboard switching do it?

Comment: @ilkkachu I'd find that both quite funny and *pötic*!

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I updated the question with details

Comment: @ilkkachu good point, I'd only use it for German stuff though where that is far less common lol

Comment: @MarcusMüller It wasn't a good idea to test this while posting here, I've ran into some *issüs*

Comment: I also use an English keyboard layout, Engl Intl with dead keys. That way I can press AltGr+q to get ä, AltGr+y to get ü, AltGr+p to get ö and AltGr+s to get ß. (Combine with shift for capital letters). I find this very convenient. Keep in mind, there are some German words that would be false positives, such as `Koexistenz`, `Bioethik`, `Poet`, ...

Comment: The proper solution to this would be a custom IME but it's probably overkill if it's only for your personal use. See e.g. https://tedyin.com/posts/a-brief-intro-to-linux-input-method-framework/

Comment: Tangentially maybe see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231410/how-can-x11-shortkeys-be-captured-by-a-python-program

Comment: Having gone through this exact problem in the 90'es with Danish, I ended up mentally resigning and just live with the Danish keyboard layout.  The effort of being non-standard was simply too much - so, very interested in seeing what is possible today 

Comment: I found it quickest to set a shortcut for switching the keyboard layout like Ctrl+Shift. That requires blind typing skills for both layouts. On my laptop I even have both layouts shown on the physical keyboard, originally it's QWERTZ, and I have added red stickers (you can buy those) with the US keys.

Answer (score 7):

X recognises a Multi_key key (or Compose), The Desktop Environment (e.g. Gnome) might use a key such as the Windows key on the keyboard to serve as the Compose key (it can be configured in Gnome keyboard settings).

By default, `Compose-o-e` generates œ.

X already provides ö via the double-inverted-commas, i.e. `Compose-"-o` generates ö (and `Compose-"-a` generates ä, etc).

If you want to override that, you can create custom settings in `~/.XCompose`
e.g.

```
# This file defines custom Compose sequences for Unicode characters

# Import default rules from the system:
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <o> <e>                     : "ö"   odiaeresis # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIARESIS
```

More documentation in `man XCompose`.

The method is related to xmodmap, cf. https://wiki.debian.org/XCompose

**Edit**: But the question requested a method that does *not* use Compose (i.e. Multi_key).  The Compose framework processes all keystrokes, so can also be adapted for the question's specific requirements, reprocessing o and e directly to form ö:

```
<o> <e>                     : "ö"   odiaeresis # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIARESIS
```

Comment: The asker said "it's annoying having to press Compose to type ä, ö, ü, ß etc", so I think they're looking for something that _doesn't_ require pressing the Compose key before the sequence.

Comment: True, in my rush to advise, I missed that particular constraint in the question. I hope the `~/.XCompose` method may nevertheless be useful for others.

Comment: Then again, XCompose is completely flexible. Answer updated to provide a direct solution without using a Compose key. Good luck writing about your shös (shoes) though ;)

Comment: You should edit it so the answer only showed what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, not the best solution, but it works:

Install node.js and the dependencies for https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook, run `npm i @nut-tree/nut-js uiohook-napi` and then run this file in Node:

```js
let binds = [
  ["ae", "ä"],
  ["oe", "ö"],
  ["ue", "ü"],
  ["sss", "ß"],
]
let sleep = ms => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,ms))
let {keyboard, Key, clipboard} = require("@nut-tree/nut-js");
let {uIOhook: io, UiohookKey: K} = require('uiohook-napi')
let maxlen = Math.max(...binds.map(e=>e[0].length))
binds=binds.map(e=>({len: e[0].length, keys: e[0].split('').map(f=>K[f.toUpperCase()])+'', out: e[1]}))
let last=Array(maxlen).fill(-1)
io.on("keydown", async e=>{
  last.push(e.keycode)
  last.shift()
  let cur = last+''
  let find = binds.find(e=>cur.endsWith(e.keys))
  if (find) {
    for (let i=0;i<find.len;i++) { await keyboard.type(Key.Backspace) }
    let cb = await clipboard.paste()
    await clipboard.copy(e.shiftKey ? find.out.toUpperCase() : find.out)
    await sleep(10)
    await keyboard.type(Key.LeftControl, Key.V)
    await sleep(10)
    await clipboard.copy(cb)
  }
})

io.start()
```

If you found something better than this, let me know because this solution is quite hacky lol

Answer (score 1):

I use us international keyboard. So german special characters are at the 3rd and 4th level of the keyboard layout

```
> cat .Xkbmap
-layout us
-variant altgr-intl

! if gnome-settings-daemon is installed execute :
! gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl')]"
! gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:caps_switch', 'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"

-option lv3:caps_switch
-option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Comment: How does this work?